# Set default team permissions on new repositories?

Tags: github

When I create a repo on GitHub, it's almost always because I have code to push that is ready for review. But by default, only the organization admin can see a new repo right after it's been created. This prevents me from adding other reviewers to the PR that I create immediately after that.

Is there a way to set this up so that everyone on my team will appear in the list of potential reviewers for every new repo as it's created?